# jenkins Parameterized Trigger Plugin to trigger another build

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have 2 jenkins box, 1st job is used for polling to trigger 2nd job.
the parameterized plugin works just perfectly, but its not working the way I wanted. So here the problem
I want to trigger 2nd job when 1st job gets "if condition" is success ( not just the build is successful ). I want the "if condition" to be true and then only trigger the 2nd job

```
status=`cat ${DIR}/CRQ-*/crqDetails.properties | grep -F ENV_VALUE_10 | cut -d '=' -f2 | tail -1`
# Checking the status of the CRQ for the execution
if [[ ${status} == "Ready" ]]; then
  echo "Executing ${CRQ}"
else 
  echo "No CRQ's for execution"
fi
```

If the $status gets matched with "Ready" then only it should trigger 2nd job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cam trigger Jenkins job with simple cURL. Look at this thread on server fault https://serverfault.com/questions/888176/how-to-trigger-jenkins-job-via-curl-command-remotely .

So your trigger would look like:

```
status=`cat ${DIR}/CRQ-*/crqDetails.properties | grep -F ENV_VALUE_10 | cut -d '=' -f2 | tail -1`
# Checking the status of the CRQ for the execution
if [[ ${status} == "Ready" ]]; then
  echo "Executing ${CRQ}"
  curl -u auto:<jenkins_user_token> http://<jenkins_server>/job/JOR_JOB/build?token=wefiytgwiefiweihfqweiodf
else 
  echo "No CRQ's for execution"
fi
```

The remotely triggered jobs can also be parametrized :).